# What is the first entrance to the airport called?

Tags: air-travel, terminology, airport-terminals

I am looking to know the terminology. I will start with the sequence in reverse so everybody understands what I'm trying to figure out -

1. Gate - This is where you are finally checked along with your boarding pass and passport before either a bus ferries you to the plane or you go on to the bridge to the plane.
2. Check-in-counter - This is where you get your boarding pass and are told which gate or terminal your flight will start from and how you should navigate.
3. Security - This is where your bags are checked to see if you are not carrying any illegal substances.
4. First gate - (the one I'm enquiring about) - This is where your printed ticket along with your passport is checked and matched with your face for the first time.

Look forward to know what is it called ?

Comment: Are you referring to airports in India?

Comment: @MichaelHampton …and Belgium?

Comment: Note that the order is not always the same and most airports don't have the step you are inquiring about. Sometimes your passport is never checked and/or matched to your ticket at all.

Comment: You can say "Terminal Entrance".  In the US, they are frequently labeled Door 1, Door 2, etc.

Comment: Yes, referring to airports in India.

Comment: Your sequence is a bit out - all airports that I have flown from have the following sequence (from arriving at the airport) - 1. Check-in and baggage drop, 2. Security, 3. Departure Lounge, 4. Gate.

Comment: And then there’s Tel Aviv airport — first security, security questioning, second questioning, check-in, passport and ticket check, security screening, immigration, departure lounge, gate. (If I didn’t forget any security, that is.)

Comment: @Moo What he's describing is an initial security check at the terminal door. This is common in some countries (India, Turkey) but unheard of elsewhere in the world. It's generally a check to ensure only passengers with tickets are allowed in the terminal building. Some places have x-ray machines at the door to detect large weapons or explosives. Later, after check-in, you go through normal airport security with your carry-ons; this is an extra step at the front door.

Comment: @ZachLipton I was in Rwanda in April and in August.  The first time, when I left, there were dogs sniffing the luggage just outside the main airport door, where they were also checking tickets and passports before examining the luggage with x-ray machines.  The second time, the luggage-sniffing dogs had been moved out to the driveway: you had to get your luggage sniffed before you even got to the parking lot, non-passengers' bags included.  The document check at the terminal entrance and the x-ray machines were unchanged.

Comment: @phoog If you go again, will they send the dogs to your hotel to check you out before you leave for the airport?

Comment: @ZachLipton I doubt it.  I suspect the security changes were related to the African Union's [2016 summit meeting](http://aukigali.rw/), which ended shortly before I arrived the second time.

Comment: ummm.... my bad. I thought/think I had put 'reverse sequence' but anyways edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That step is not so common but I've seen it in some airports.

I know of no official name but I would call it *Passenger Entrance* since this is also where those who are not passengers cannot usually go since they have no tickets.

Comment: thank you. Came to know it is known either as 'Passenger entrance' or 'Terminal entrance' either is good.